Minimize header on sticky scroll is causing flicker in NextJS?
I'm trying to code a sticky header which minimizes on scroll in NextJS. It's working fine. But there's a flicker between the transition of header. How can we fix this? Here's the code:
const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  if(window.screenY > 180){
    const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
    const isScrolled = window.scrollY > 180;
    
    if (isScrolled !== scrolled) {
      setScrolled(!scrolled);
    }
  };
    
  document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
}, [scrolled]);

Header
<header className={`z-50 px-6 lg:px-24 ${scrolled ? 'py-3 md:py-4 backdrop-blur-3xl dark:backdrop-brightness-50 bg-white/30 dark:bg-black/30 border-b border-black/[0.1] dark:border-white/[0.1] sticky top-0' : 'py-5 md:py-7 bg-transparent'}`}>
      <div className='xl:container columns-2 mx-auto flex items-center'>
        <div className={`w-full flex justify-start items-center ${scrolled ? 'h-auto' : 'h-[72px]'}`}>
          <Link href='/' title='Inside Dynamics'>
            {scrolled ? <LogoMini /> : <Logo />}
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className={`w-full flex justify-end items-center ${scrolled ? 'h-auto' : 'h-[72px] py-6'}`}>
          <menu className='text:black dark:text-white font-light hidden md:block'>
            <li className='inline pb-1 border-primary hover:border-b mr-8 cursor-pointer'><a href='/#services'>Services</a></li>
            <li className='inline pb-1 border-primary hover:border-b mr-8 cursor-pointer'><a href='/#pricing'>Pricing</a></li>
            <li className='inline pb-1 border-primary hover:border-b mr-8 cursor-pointer'><a href='/#reviews'>Reviews</a></li>
            <li className='inline pb-1 border-primary hover:border-b mr-8 cursor-pointer'><a href='/#faq'>FAQ</a></li>
            <li className='inline pb-1 border-primary hover:border-b cursor-pointer'><Link href='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
          </menu>
          <div className={`flex justify-center items-center ${scrolled ? 'ml-6' : 'ml-8'}`}>
            <ThemeSwitch />
            <button className='border border-neutral-200 hover:bg-neutral-50 active:border-primary dark:border-neutral-500 dark:hover:bg-neutral-950 p-4 ml-3 rounded-full block md:hidden' aria-label='Mobile Menu'>
              <RiMenu4Line className='size-5'/>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>


To fix this annoyance, we can make the code a bit smarter. Instead of updating the state every single time you scroll even a tiny bit, we'll wait a bit after you stop scrolling before updating the state.
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
      const isScrolled = window.scrollY > 180;
      setScrolled(isScrolled);
    }, 100); // Adjust the debounce delay as needed

    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

Check if this resolve the issue.

It is still blinking but now quite slowly
